# I need to delay the expansion of my groups in my ExpandableListView

Tags: android, animation, expandablelistview

I need to delay the expansion of my groups in my ExpandableListView for a couple of milliseconds until the content of the child elements is loaded.
I am using a custom adapter which I extend with BaseExpandableListAdapter.

Does anyone know a method to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Handler` and post a delayed `Runnable` containing your code.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
//Code here
}, 1000);
```